# R: expand and fill data frame by date in series

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the raw data frame:

```
igroup=c("A", "B", "C")
demo_df=data.frame(date=c("2018-11-28", "2018-12-17", "2019-01-23"), group)
```

Raw data frame:

```
      date   group
1 2018-11-28     A
2 2018-12-17     B
3 2019-01-23     C
```

I want to have a data frame that expand the date to next column but still keep the group information. For example, date from 2018-11-28 to 2018-12-16 is with group A, date from 2018-12-17 to 2019-01-22 is with group B and 2019-01-23 is with group C.

This is the output (`result_df`) I want:

```
time=c(seq(as.Date("2018-11-28"), as.Date("2018-12-17")-1, by=1), 
seq(as.Date("2018-12-17"), as.Date("2019-01-23")-1, by=1),as.Date("2019-01-23") )
group1=c(rep("A",as.numeric(as.Date("2018-12-17")-as.Date("2018-11-28"))), 
rep("B",as.numeric(as.Date("2019-01-23")-as.Date("2018-12-17"))), "C" )
result_df=data.frame(time,group1 )
result_df
```

I am wondering if there is any more efficient way (using `dplyr`) to handle this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure `date` is stored as a date object:

```
demo_df$date <- as.Date(demo_df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then using `tidyverse`, we first `complete` the sequence, then `fill` the group down:

```
library(tidyverse)

demo_df %>% complete(date = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by = "day")) %>% 
 fill(igroup)
```

Comment: Wow! So `tidyverse` is the key! Thank you so much! I appreciate it! I should practice `tidyverse` from today...

Comment: @Joanna like many things, there is more than one way to do this, but `tidyverse` affords a nice, compact, readable solution in many cases, including this one.

Comment: thanks for sharing. What is the difference between `dplyr` and `tidyverse`? I just know that they are very popular...

Comment: @Joanna `dplyr` is actually part of `tidyverse`. `tidyverse` represents a collection of packages designed for working with data in R. The all share a similar logical framework in terms of how they're used, and together, they provide a powerful set of tools to work with diverse problems and data sets. More info here: https://www.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for sharing! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Going through this years later, here is a variation on [Mako212's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54374169):

```
demo_df %>% complete(date=full_seq(date,1)) %>% fill(group)
```